# What is this as a for loop not list comprehension?

Tags: python

I came across a program and want to know what the program would be without the list comprehensions. Shown below is the code Thank You:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence = sentence.lower().split()
uniquewords = []
for word in sentence:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(word)

positions = [uniquewords.index(word) for word in sentence]
recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])

print (positions)
print (recreated)
```

Comment: It would throw an error, 'recreated' uses the variables in the list 'positions'. 'Recreated' returns a string of parsed words located at the indices specified in positions

Comment: Try reading the docs on list comprehensions? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: I just assumed the OP was asking about a literal deletion, not a reworking

Comment: No, wait. It's worse: it just rebuilds the original list. The only change is that it's all lowercase and words are spaced by a single space... So I'm pretty sure this is just a bad way of writing `" ".join(sentence.lower().split())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension can be replaced by a more-or-less equivalent `for` loop. Consider these two snippets:

```
# 1
a = [f(b) for b in expression]

# 2
a = []
for b in expression:
    a.append(f(b))
```

You can see how the elements of the list comprehension appear in the expanded `for` loop.

These two list comprehensions:

```
positions = [uniquewords.index(word) for word in sentence]
recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])
```

Are roughly equivalent to:

```
positions = []
for word in sentence:
    positions.append(uniquewords.index(word)
recreated_temp = []
for i in positions:
    recreated_temp.append(uniquewords[i])
recreated = " ".join(recreated_temp)
```